# How to check proxy settings in Leiningen ? (Clojure)

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I want to check if Windows ENV variable `http_proxy` is picked properly by Leiningen. I've found a function [`get-proxy-settings`](https://leiningen.org/reference.html)  but can't understand how to call it properly. Seems I have to use namespace `leiningen.core.classpath` somehow for this? 
This is my second day to learn Clojure and I am not familiar with namespaces yet.

Answer (score 3):

Just try your proxy settings in your environment and see if it works. It should work automatically.

But if you must, you can call `leiningen.core.classpath/get-proxy-settings` from your project definition by using unquote. Minimal example:

```
(defproject proxy-settings "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-pprint "1.1.2"]]
  :debug/proxy ~(leiningen.core.classpath/get-proxy-settings))
```

Note the `lein-pprint` plugin there.

Use `lein pprint` to see the value of `:debug/proxy`.